# Use the Chinese Reminder Theorem to find; (1030 ∗ 989) mod 3003.

Tags: number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

I have found a lot of help online for solving a system of congruences but I am not sure what to do with this?

I am having a lot of trouble with the Chinese Remainder Theorem in general, but this one is throwing me for a curve since it's not like most of the questions I have found online.

As stated:
Use the Chinese Reminder Theorem to find (1030 ∗ 989) mod 3003.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: $3003=1001 \cdot 3$; is the problem easier modulo these numbers?

Comment: Hint 2: $\bmod 1001\!:\ x\equiv 29(-12)\,$  so $\bmod 3\!:\ x\equiv \overbrace{29(-12)+1001\color{#c00}k\equiv 1030(989)}^{\Large\    (29) 0\ +\ \color{#c00}{2k\ \equiv\ 1(2)}}\iff \color{#c00}{k\equiv 1}$ $\quad$ $\quad$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call your unknown $x$. Going off the hint 3*1001=3003, you can rewrite your single congruence as:

\begin{align*}
x &\equiv (1003)(989) \mod 3 \\
x &\equiv (1003)(989) \mod 1001
\end{align*}
which, taking mods, simplifies to
\begin{align*}
x &\equiv (1)(2) \mod 3 \\
x &\equiv (2)(-12) \mod 1001
\end{align*}

Since $\mod 1001$ is still a bit unwieldy, you can repeat this process using $1001 = 7\cdot143$ and $143=11\cdot 13$ until you get a system of 4 congruences. Then apply CRT.